# how to set a value to list or text box using wxWidgets library

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've been struggling with converting the numbers on my buttons to the text box for my assignment. Basically what I'm trying to do is when a user presses for example when I click on 7 it should appear in the text box but currently in my Button Pressed method it only puts in a . instead of 7 and I'm not too familiar with the wxWidgets library classes. is there another command or method I can use?

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(calMain, wxFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(100, ButtonPressed)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
    
calMain::calMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Calculator UI!", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(335, 545))
{
    wxFont font(15, wxFONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_BOLD, false);
    m_txt1 = new wxTextCtrl(this,wxID_ANY, " ",wxPoint(0, 21), wxSize(322, 50));
    CalButton = new wxButton(this, 100, "7", wxPoint(30, 156), wxSize(50, 70));
    CalButton->SetFont(font);
}
void calMain::ButtonPressed(wxCommandEvent& evt) 
{
        m_txt1->SetLabelText(CalButton->GetLabelText());
        evt.Skip();
}
```

Comment: This looks fine. Can you add a `cout` after the `SetLableText` call like `std::cout<<m_txt1->GetLabelText();` to confirm if the text has changed or not and maybe this is only a display problem. For example like this: `void calMain::ButtonPressed(wxCommandEvent& evt){m_txt1->SetLabelText(CalButton->GetLabelText());std::cout<<m_txt1->GetLabelText();evt.Skip();
}`

Comment: You can but that just gives the same result

Comment: @Cp, Take a look at you event binding line: `EVT_BUTTON(100, ButtonPressed)`. It shuold be `EVT_BUTTON(100, calMain::ButtonPressed)`. See the difference? And so the code as written in the OP will NOT work at all.

Comment: Also, for future reference - please mention wx version, and OS you are working under. Sometimes those stuff do matter.

Comment: I understand I'm using the 3.2.0 version and I'm using Visual Studios, but using calMain::ButtonPressed doesn't change anything since I'm including calMain.h. Also the last lines of code yes I know they don't work.

Comment: @Cp, it doesn't matter what you include- the code as written is incorrect and you should fix it. Now as to why it still produces wrong results - did you try to debug it? Did you check the documentation of wxButton to see what the correct call is?

Comment: Also independent of that - you should start using sizers and stop using hard-coded position/size. Will save a lot of headache in the long run.

Comment: Finally, for the reference - when replying start with `@<name>`. That way the person you reply to will get notified about the reply .

Comment: @Igor I tried using a sizer but it just locks the buttons on top of each other besides I'm pretty sure I can't implement something like that for this assignment. I need to make something called a button factory next which will replace all the buttons I've made so far.

Comment: @Cp, is this a homework? Also, it doesn't matter what you will implement - you need to understand that absolute positioning will not give you a flexibility of changing OS, theme or DPI. Now - can you do a sketch of what layout you are after.

Comment: @Cp, and is the original problem fixed after fixing event table and debugging the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wxTextCtrl::SetValue()` (or `ChangeValue()`, which is very similar, but doesn't generate any events about the change in the text control) to change the *value* (*not* the label) of `wxTextCtrl`.